# to generate charts along with sorted data which has to export to word from sqlserver where data is stored

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

old process:-
1) data pulled from web survery
2) moved into the central repository sql database 
3) pulled from sql server manually and then moved over into excel sheet again manually where macros run to produce charts and sorted data in table formats , which export to word document with button click.

New process has to migrate:-
1) need to automate of 3rd step totally, i.e a logic need to run on sqlserver which automatically export charts and data in sorted data in table format (e.g student certification information and pie charts of many certification done)

the whole manual process in above 3rd step has to automate. can you please suggest me better solution. how can be automated using ssis, ssrs ?

finally charts , sorted student information , certification information has to export to word document in structured manner.

Comment: There's a steep learning curve if you haven't done it before, but SSRS subscriptions work really well for this type of use case.

Comment: Word is not a typical output from either SSIS or SSRS. You can however send PDFs from SSRS on a subscription. Excel is an output of SSIS, but not in the format of charts.